# How to concurrently upsert documents in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am working on real-time distributed system with multiple nodes writing updates to the same MongoDb collection.

For simplicity sake the document look like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: foo,
  version: 1
}
```

On updates version guaranteed to increase but there is possibility so the messages arrive out of order.
I need to always save the latest version to the collection.

In SQL I would do something like this:

```
  BEGIN TRAN
 
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM myTable WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE id= @id )
 
      UPDATE myTable
         SET Name= @Name,
             Version = @Version
       WHERE Id = @id 
       AND Version < @Version
 
    ELSE 
 
      INSERT myTable ( Id, Name, Version )
      VALUES ( @Id, @Name, @Version );
 
  COMMIT
```

UPDATE in response to comments:
Here is what I tried:

```
await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(
   x => x.Id == id && x.Version <= payload.Version,
   options: new ReplaceOptions {IsUpsert = true},
   replacement: payload 
);
```

When trying to update existing document get this exception:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException : A write operation resulted in an error.
> E11000 duplicate key error collection: TEST_948e4e5acae041cca607e9f523dc0194.TestEntityParent index: *id* dup key: { _id: 500 }

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#syntax upsert:true

Comment: @AlexBlex, how to specify condition `Version < @Version`? 
I tried filter `{id: 1, version: { $lt: 123} }` but it tries to insert duplicate

Comment: Add unique key for id. The filter is correct.

Comment: The filter like that is like having both criteria in the `IF EXISTS` clause.  In order to get MongoDB to behave the way you want, you'll need to use the pipeline form of update, with a `$cond` expression.

Comment: @Joe, that's interesting. Using $cond, how do you know whether update was successful or failed because of the stale version?

Comment: @Joe, exactly my point. having that filter in place prevent from finding record by id and every operation become an insert, that fails as duplicate. Can you post an answer with an example of how to construct such a pipeline?

Comment: @MichaelD. isn't it intended behaviour? What do you expect from an update where version is not greater than the one in the database?

Comment: If version on updated document is greater than one in database it should replace the document in DB.
Also if the stale document is processed i do not want to have an exception thrown, it should silently ignore the update

Comment: Ah, that explains the confusion. It's not usual practice since most application implement some retrying logic. In your case just suppress the exception.

Comment: The [response](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#returns) from the update command shows how many documents matched, how many were modified, and how many upserted.  Using `$cond` to check the date, if the document matched, but nothing was modified, that would imply the update was stale, right?

Comment: @Joe, I see what you mean but I **guess** $cond will trigger update counter regardless of condition in it. Didn't check it  tho. Could you post it as an answer to try how it works. I am really curious.

Comment: @Joe, Please provide a sample as an answer, I am having troubles to build such a pipeline using C# driver.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how do this with C#.  An example of updating using `$cond` via the mongo shell:

```
function testUpdate(updated, value) {
    return db.test.update(
             {test: 1},
             [{$set: {
                     monkies: {
                         $cond:{
                            if: {$or:[
                                      {$gt: [updated, "$version"]},
                                      {$eq: [{$type:"$version"},"missing"]}
                            ]},
                            then: value,
                            else: "$monkies"
                         }
                     },
                     version: {
                         $cond:{
                            if: {$or:[
                                      {$gt: [updated, "$version"]},
                                      {$eq: [{$type:"$version"},"missing"]}
                            ]},
                            then: updated,
                            else: "$version"
                         }
                     }
             }}],
             {upsert: true}
     
    )
}
```

The first update against an empty collection matches nothing, and upserts 1 document:

```
replset:PRIMARY> testUpdate(1,1)
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e2116d7a583eef6ad49f9")
})
```

An update with a greater version matches 1 document, and modifies 1:

```
replset:PRIMARY> testUpdate(2,3)
WriteResult({ 
     "nMatched" : 1, 
     "nUpserted" : 0, 
     "nModified" : 1 
})
```

An update with a lesser version matches 1 document, but updates 0:

```
replset:PRIMARY> testUpdate(1,4)
WriteResult({ 
    "nMatched" : 1, 
    "nUpserted" : 0, 
    "nModified" : 0 
})
```

The resultant document after all of these:

```
replset:PRIMARY> db.test.find()
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f6e2116d7a583eef6ad49f9"), 
  "test" : 1, 
  "monkies" : 3, 
  "version" : 2 
}
```

Comment: thank you! I am very new to Mongo Db so trying to make sense from your example.

How can I change the $set to $replaceWith? I am not able to do property update - I need to replace entire document.

Comment: If you use `$replaceWith` instead of `$set`, it will remove all others fields not mentioned, so you just need to repeat any fields you want saved in addition to the ones you want changed.