# Duplicate key error from MongoDB on Upsert operation

Tags: mongodb, upsert

We have a case where we get `E11000 Duplicate key error in BatchWriteOperation` from MongoDB.
This at first sight looks extremely odd as this document is only updated using upserts.
Which conceptually shouldn't really allow duplicate keys to occur.

We came across this description of the problem:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322

[image]

Our Upsert expression is as follows (C#)

```
var l = await _pids.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.Id == id && x.LockedBy == null, updatedDocument,
    new ReplaceOptions
    {
        IsUpsert = true
    }
);
```

`Id` is the normal `_id` of the document, and `LockedBy` is a non indexed property of the document.

Is the reason why we are getting duplicate key errors here, because the predicate in the find part of the update, consists of multiple props?

We could ofcourse just have a retry around this. but we are very interested in knowing why we get this, which of the above rules applies to us in this case?

Comment: Can you start with the query you are sending, describe expected behavior, describe actual behavior, then describe what you suspect the problem is? I cannot follow the question as written.

Comment: The expected behavior for me, would be that an Upsert _always_ succeeds, unless you are in a transaction. but, this is not the case, there are conditions, as described in the link, where an upsert can fail.

And to me, it is not at all clear how that maps to the Upsert that we are doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReplaceOneAsync will try to upsert the document if there is not a matching one found.

If a document with a matching _id already exists, but is locked, there will be not matching document, and so the upsert will be attempted.

This upsert will fail (as it should) because there is already a document with that _id value, and there is a unique index on _id.

Comment: So the answer here is that there is a conflict between the predicate and what is being updated/inserted?

the predicate is wider, more fields than the unique indexes on that collection?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054051/how-to-concurrently-upsert-documents-in-mongodb